# How to add a field for each aggregated group in mongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My dataset looks like this:

```
{key: A, leader: Anna, value: 10}
{key: A, leader: Anna, value: 10}
{key: A, leader: Anna, value: 40}
```

I'm grouping by the key and averaging the value, but I would also need to show the leader, which is always the same for each key.

My target result is:

```
{Key: A, leader: Anna, average_value= 20}
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
  {
        $match: {value: { $qte: 1 }  }
      },
      {
        $group: { _id: "$key", average_value: { $avg: "$value" } }
      }
```

I tried using $addFields but found no suitable operator.

Comment: Try: `{$group: { _id: "$key", leader: {$first: "$leader" }, average_value: { $avg: "$value" } } }` or use it inside the `_id`: `{$group: { _id: {key: "$key", leader: "$leader" }, average_value: { $avg: "$value" } } }`